# How to deserialize JSON to immutable object in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

So I've been trying to convert JSON to an immutable object for an API, and I've just hit wall after wall with it. The `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConstructor` attribute doesn't seem to work at all. Here's an example of the record.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
namespace App.Foobar{
   public record Foo
   {
      [JsonConstructor]
      public Foo(decimal bar){
         Bar = bar;
      }

      [JsonIgnore]
      public decimal Bar {get;}
   }
}
```

And the JSON I'm passing in;

```
{
   foo: {
      bar: 12
   }
}
```

So how would I deserialize JSON into this class? Is there something I'm doing wrong with the JSON I'm passing in, or is it a problem in the class?

I need to preserve the `JsonIgnore` attribute, as well.

Comment: This may depend on more details regarding how you are invoking the deserialization, but generally with JSON the property names and values are separated by colons rather than equals signs, and the class name isn't involved. So I would expect your sample JSON to look like `{ bar: 12 }` (SO comments don't allow multi-line formatting).

Comment: @DanielSmith Yeah, I didn't realize I had put an equals sign in there, it's a bad habit. As for the name being there, it's because I'm deserializing my object from another object, so to make it more true to how I'm doing it, I just put the name in it.

Comment: If these are the Domain DTOs then I won't worry about making them Mutable! But then I would create a Model (make these models Immutable!) that I can interact from Presentation Layer. I would Map Domain DTOs to Presentation Model, https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html and other tools exists for that reason. Go through that link and you will find what I'm trying to explain here. Hope it make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the [JsonIgnoreAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=net-6.0) applies to both serialization and deserialization, and this is something you cannot change.

So in short, if you have `[JsonIgnore]`, you won't be able to get its value from deserializing JSON data, no matter what.

As a workaround, you cuold play with read-only properties, or null-valued properties or even default-valued properties since you can set serialization options for these.  See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0) for more information.

In general, you can read about [immutable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability?source=recommendations&pivots=dotnet-6-0) as Microsoft has envisioned them to make sure you don't try to do weird stuff.

### AutoMapper Workaround

You can also work around this using **AutoMapper**.  You can have a private record class that does not ignore the `bar` property and then map it to a public record class that does ignore said property.

And actually, I don't know if **AutoMapper** works with `record`.  Test it out.  If not, do the mapping yourself.

Comment: So how does `[JsonConstructor]` work? I read in the source that you gave me (I've read it before) that you can essentially use it to deserialize it into the constructor, instead of directly into the class. If that's not the case, then how does `[JsonConstructor]` work?

Comment: That IS the case.  The parameter's names must match the property names in a case-insensitive way.  Any renaming via the `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` is ignored.  What is not ignored is `JsonIgnoreAttribute`.  If you ignore a property, it is ignored for deserialization as well.  Apply a workaround.